# Cluster-based permutation analysis on multiple factors using lmer

Tags: time-series, mixed-model, permutation-test

I'm analysing eye-tracking data mostly using `eyetrackingR`, and one thing I started doing recently is bootstrapped cluster-based permutation analysis, as described on [the `eyetrackingR` website](http://www.eyetracking-r.com/vignettes/divergence). It strikes me that complex statistics such as mixed-effect models can be used to test statistical differences at each time-bin, however the implementation of the permutation analysis itself allows for comparisons only between levels of one factor.

To give you a bit more context, I want to study differences in looking between the first few and last few trials (`FstLst`, within-subjects) and depending on the presence/absence of an auditory label (`Condition`, between-subjects). At the minutes, the only two ways I can see to include information from both my factors into the cluster analysis is to run two analyses, one for each level of `FstLst`, or using a "combined" factor `FstLst_Condition` that would thus have 4 levels (`First_Label`, `First_NoLabel` and so on), but neither option is really satisfactory.

So the question in the end really is: how would one run a cluster-based permutation analysis depending on multiple factors?